# Bug in my Minimum Spanning Tree implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I'm trying to implement the kruskal's algorithm which finds the minimum spanning tree at a undirected, weighted graph G(V,E). My implementation uses disjoint sets to make the algorithm faster. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::sort;
using std::vector;

const int MAXV =  1000;

struct set_union {
  set_union *parent;
  int rank;
} *array[MAXV];

set_union* make_set() {
  set_union *ret = new set_union();
  ret->parent = NULL;
  ret->rank = 1;
  return ret;
}

set_union* find_root(set_union *u) {
  set_union *temp = u;
  while(temp->parent != NULL) {
    temp = temp->parent;
  }
  return temp;
}

void union_sets(set_union *&pa, set_union *&pb) {
  set_union *a = find_root(pa), *b = find_root(pb);
  if(a->rank > b->rank) {
    b->parent = a;
  } else if(a->rank < b->rank) {
    a->parent = b;
  } else {
    a->parent = b;
    a->rank++;
  }
}

bool same_component(set_union *a, set_union *b) {
  return find_root(a) == find_root(b);
}

struct link {
  int v;
  int w;
};

struct edge {
  int v,u;
  int w;
};

bool operator < (const edge& a, const edge& b) {
  if(a.w < b.w) { return true; }
  else { return false; }
}

struct graph {
  vector<vector<link> > adj;
  vector<edge> edges;
  int V,E;
  graph(int v) : adj(v), edges(0), V(v), E(0) {}
};

void insert(graph &g, int a, int b, int c = 1) {
  g.edges.push_back((edge) {a,b,c});
  g.adj[a].push_back((link) {b,c});
  g.adj[b].push_back((link) {a,c});
}

void kruskal(graph g, vector<edge> &tree) {
  printf("Entering kruskal\n");
  tree.clear();
  for(int i = 0; i < g.V; i++) {
    array[i] = make_set();
  }

  printf("sorting edges by weight\n");
  sort(g.edges.begin(), g.edges.end());
  int i;

  printf("Entering while\n");
  while(tree.size() < g.V-1 && i < g.E) {
    if(!same_component(array[g.edges[i].v], array[g.edges[i].u])) { /* Here is the error */
      tree.push_back(g.edges[i]);
      union_sets(array[g.edges[i].v], array[g.edges[i].u]);
     }
    i++;
  }
  printf("Exiting kruskal\n");
}


int main(void) {
  int v,e;
  scanf("%d %d", &v, &e);

  graph g(v);

  for (int i = 0; i < e; ++i) {
    int a,b,c;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    insert(g,a,b,c);
  }

  vector<edge> tree;
  kruskal(g,tree);

  for ( vector<edge >::iterator it = tree.begin(); it < tree.end(); ++it ) {
    printf("%d %d w = %d\n", it->v, it->u, it->w);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles without errors, but it gives me no results. For example when I give it this input:

```
3 3
0 1 1
1 2 1
2 0 2
```

it doesn't produce any output at all. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I have spotted where I think the error is with a comment. As the `tree` is empty, I conclude that `if(!same_component(array[g.edges[i].v], array[g.edges[i].u]))` is always `false`. So the mistake must be at the `same_component` function, but I cannot spot it.

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: `printf`? `scanf`? `MAGIC_BUFFER_SIZE`? Ewww. I ain't gonna guess the error in *that*.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I ran the program at the paper, the output was correct. The error is not at the algorithm, but at the `set_union` implementation.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: Ok, well like I said, use the debugger, etc. to follow the flow of your program to figure out why it's not doing what you expect.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are correct. With some `printf`s I spotted the error. When I inserted into the graph, I didn't increase the number of the edges by 1.So the error was at the `insert` function. So stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `kruskal()` function, you aren't initialising `i` before testing its value with `while(tree.size() < g.V-1 && i < g.E)`.  It will contain rubbish (whatever was in already memory), which will probably cause the loop not to execute even once.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but when I execute the program it gives me the correct answer, without initializing `i`. But you are right I should initialize it anyway

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: I guess you got "lucky" and the memory behind `i` happened to already be 0 or some low number.  Some compilers (e.g. MSVC++ with the `/RTCs` option -- also see `/RTCu`) allow stack memory to be filled with "unlikely" values to help in finding these bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The error is at the `insert` function. When I insert an edge at the graph, I don't increase the total number of the graph's edges. So the while loop at the Kruscal function never executes.